# How can I get the application name of Ruby on Rails app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I get the Ruby on Rails application name via code that is deployed on Heroku?

Comment: we need app-name in model as well as controllers

Comment: Please clarify your question because it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Application name ? application name never change you can make it constant if you are asking for rails app. Or you want heroku application name ? So it's also have hosted on multiple heroku instance. Clarify your question with more detail.

Comment: i want to get heroku application(instance) name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Rails.application.class.parent_name
```

should do it